# Find minimum of two values in Python

Tags: python, minimum

How to program this expression in Python:

```
min{cos(2xπ), 1/2}
```

?

I have tried:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,5,7])

solution = np.min(np.cos(2*x*np.pi), 1/2)
```

But it does not work, and there is the following mistake:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

[image: Screenshot of my code]

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Thank you!

Comment: are you meaning `cos` of each value in x ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar Yes, cos of each value in x is a part of solution

Comment: I used your inputs and got an answer of `1.0` in `IPython`. I don't understand why `jupyter` is giving you an error. You can try creating temporary variables to store intermediate results. I am using `Python 2`. Are you on `Python 3`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short Python Code to say "Pick the lower value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432211/short-python-code-to-say-pick-the-lower-value)

Comment: `numpy.min` expects second parameter to be `axis` which you are passing as`1/2`, Thats why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code with `np.minimum` like this :

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,3,2,5,7])

solution = np.minimum(np.cos(2*x*np.pi), 1/2)
print(solution)
```

which gives something like this :

```
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5  0.5]
```

the minimum function will check through each element of array and returns an array. you can take a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html)

Comment: Actually, with both python 2 and 3, I get output `[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]` (yes, `0.`, not `0.5`)

Comment: @ChatterOne iam giving here a link you can check the code there : https://repl.it/repls/NimbleWhisperedHalicore

Comment: This is correct solution if you want element wise minimum.